# Find intersection with line when know cx,cy center of circle with radius r, line ends at dx,dy

Tags: geometry

It was been 35 years since I took geometry in high school. ;)

Here is my problem.  Find intersection with line when know cx,cy center of circle with radius r, line ends at dx,dy.

I know it has to be something to do with right triangle.  Perfect would be like code in C# or javascript.  I am just trying to find the point where the circle and line intersect.  Basically, want to start the line where the line intersects not at the center of the circle.

[This is an image of what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCpAc.png)

Comment: Form the equation of the line, using the two points provided. Then substitute the value of y into the equation of the circle, get the value of x, and subsequently the value of y.

Answer (score 0):

1. Compute the distance from $c$ to $d$:

$$s=\sqrt{(d_x-c_x)^2+(d_y-c_y)^2}$$

Therefore, the distance from $\ell$ to $d$ is $s-r$.

2. Now express that $\ell$ is the weighted average of $c$ and $d$ with the resp. weights $\tfrac{s-r}{s}$ and $\tfrac{r}{s}$ (whose sum is $1$):

$$\binom{\ell_x}{\ell_y}=\tfrac{s-r}{s}\binom{c_x}{c_y}+\tfrac{r}{s}\binom{d_x}{d_y}$$

Otherwise said :

$$\begin{cases}\ell_x&=&\tfrac{(s-r)c_x+rd_x}{s}\\
\ell_y&=&\tfrac{(s-r)c_y+rd_y}{s}\end{cases}$$

Comment: No comment on this solution ?

Comment: Thank you very much